# C method vs Objective C method

Tags: objective-c, methods

How can you write a Objective C method in C?

Can someone explain how a objC method works?

As far as i know, Objective C method is a function call where it targets itself and tells object that it is performing a function.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. Do you have some sample code that you aren't understanding? Do you understand either C or Objective-C but not both? Can you concentrate just on understanding the language syntax before comparing them...

Comment: A method is a word that refers to O.O.P. language.
C is not a O.O.P. language.

Answer (score 2):

> How can you write a Objective C method in C?

You can't. But you can write C functions in an Objective-C code file (though you don't usually want to).

> Can someone explain how a objC method works?

Similar to a function, but a function is not OO so it has no concept of the object (`self`). A method is called on an object instance and operates on the data contained within that object. This is really an OO thing, not an Objective-C thing.

> As far as i know, Objective C method is a function call where it targets itself and tells object that it is performing a function.

As said, not really a function, but it does target an object instance.

Generally speaking, don't try to compare OO and functional / procedural languages. There are significant differences. Initially, understand the differences between OO and functional, and then understand the syntax of the particular language you're trying to work with.